# Breeze error Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, breeze

Error when specified $filter `{{api}}/Person/Get?$filter=substringof('rid', Name) eq true`

### Error

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$type": "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Take[BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person](.OrderBy[BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person,System.Int32](.Where[BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person], Quote(($it, ) => (Equal(Equal(Or(Equal(Convert($it.Name), NULL), p1) ? NULLp3 : Convert(Convert($it.Name).Contains(p2, )), p4), p5))), ), Quote(($it, ) => ($it.Id)), ), p6, )]",
        "ExceptionType": "NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException",
        "StackTrace": "   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(String collectionRole)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)"
    }
}
```

When **not** specified a filter works! `{{api}}/Person/Get?`

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person, BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model",
    "Name": "Riderman de Sousa Barbosa",
    "NickName": "ridermansb",
    "Id": 1,
    "CreateAt": "2013-06-21T19:38:27.000",
    "UpdateAt": "2013-06-21T19:38:27.000"
},
{
    "$id": "2",
    "$type": "BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person, BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model",
    "Name": "Felipe de Sousa Barbosa",
    "NickName": "felipegerais",
    "Id": 2,
    "CreateAt": "2013-06-21T19:38:35.000",
    "UpdateAt": "2013-06-21T19:38:35.000"
},
{
    "$id": "3",
    "$type": "BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model.Person, BreezeWithNHiberbate.Model",
    "Name": "Maria Helena de Sousa",
    "NickName": " lelena",
    "Id": 3,
    "CreateAt": "2013-06-21T19:38:41.000",
    "UpdateAt": "2013-06-21T19:38:41.000"
}
```

### Source code

```
public class Person : Auditable
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string NickName { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Auditable : IAuditable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreateAt { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UpdateAt { get; protected set; }
}

public interface IAuditable : IEntity
{
    DateTime CreateAt { get; }
    DateTime? UpdateAt { get; }
}
```

Full [code here](https://bitbucket.org/ridermansb/illustrateproblems/src) in `BreezeWithNHiberbate` folder;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that NHibernate's LINQ provider is choking on the filter expression because of null checking.  Null checking wraps every filter parameter in an expression that NH LINQ can't handle.

WebApi OData turns off null checking for EF, Linq2Sql, and Linq2Objects, but turns it on for everything else.  To turn it off, add

```
HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False
```

to your Querable attribute.  So in your BaseApiController, you would have

```
[HttpGet, Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False, PageSize = 20)]
public IQueryable<T> Get()
{
    return Repositorio.All();
}
```

Note that if you use `[BreezeNHController]` (that's `Breeze.Nhibernate.WebApi.BreezeNHControllerAttribute`) instead of `[BreezeController]`, it automatically applies this option to all the IQueryable methods.  It also adds extra logic for handling $expand and for controlling lazy loading during serialization.

Official Breeze support for NHibernate is coming soon.  Glad to see you are working with it already.

Comment: If I use `Breeze.Nhibernate.WebApi.BreeNHController` it will automatically apply this option?  I downloaded the [DLL on github](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Nhibernate/Breeze.Nhibernate.WebApi/Breeze.Nhibernate.WebApi.dll) and added to the project, but still the error occurs. When I add the option manually works!

Comment: The `[BreezeNHController]` attribute applies the `[BreezeNHQueryable]` attribute to all methods that don't already have a `[Queryable]` attribute applied.  So try removing your `[Queryable]` attributes on your methods when you put the `[BreezeNHController]` on your controller.

Comment: I've been scratching my head over this. Thanks @SteveSchmitt, your solution works!